# different ways to use express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I can set express middleware like this:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    console.log("my middleware");
    return next();
});
```

And also like this:

```
app.get("/", function(req,res,next) {
     console.log("my other middleware");
},
function(req,res) {
     res.send("Test");
});
```

Aside from the fact that the first case is applied globally to all routes, and in the second case it is only applied to the specific route "/", do these behave identically?

Comment: Let's make it harder to answer by using `app.all("/*", middleware, ...)` :->

Comment: I did notice app.all, which made it even more confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two differences.  The first is correct... the first middleware is used for all requests and the second one is for anything matching your route of `/`.

The second difference is that the first middleware is used for all verbs, whereas the second middleware is only use for `GET` requests.